# Google Drives SDK and powerpoint

Tags: java, android, metadata, powerpoint, google-drive-api

I am currently developing a small android app using the google drive SDK/google doc's embedded player which will play through power point files in a slide-show manner. Since there's no direct way I can tell when one powerpoint ends and another begins using the SDK, I was wondering if there was any way for me to retrieve the number of slides from a power point. With the amount of slides I'll be attempting to use the interval between slide changes to calculate the time taken for each powerpoint to play and then using that I can switch through files. I know .pptx files carry the amount of slides in it's metadata (not so sure about .ppt), but I'm not sure how to go on reading it. I've looked at google drive SDK's part to read metadata, but it seems rather limited to what you can actually read. I've looked at ApachePOI but it doesn't seem it's android compatible. Could anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible using the Google Drive SDK. You could easily download the pptx, unzip it (it is just zipped XML) and extract the required metadata.